# how to send user data to xml through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following is my code to send data (formatted XML) but it gives an error. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "XMLFile1.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: "<event><text>text</text> <date>date</date></event>",
    success: function () {
        alert("msg sent");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: here text and date are two variables

Comment: "it gives error" — What is "it"? The server? The JavaScript? What is the error? Quote the error message.

Comment: How does one send data to an XML file ?

Comment: There are at least two (wildly different) things wrong with the code in the question, but I wouldn't expect either of them to lead to an error message (at least, not without other code making assumptions). You really should do some basic debugging to see what it is you are sending to the server and what you are getting back. The Net tab of your browser's developer tools could help with that.

Comment: error means that the code leads to the error event handler of this function

Comment: I have checked I am sending non null values to the server .....how can i check the reason for the error

Comment: @nagia — Then you need to find out why the error handler gets called. The JavaScript console of your developer tools might help you. Looking at the request and the response in the Net tab of your developer tools might help you. Looking at the arguments passed to the error handler might help you. You need to do some basic debugging to find out what the error is.

Comment: ok my debugging showed me this error "Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null"                                               what does this mean?

Comment: I am still stuck on the same problem ..can anybody help please?